# How to change background color of inner area of Google Donut hole?

Tags: javascript, css, google-api, google-visualization, donut-chart

I'm using Google Pie Chart API and trying to create this UI

[image]

This is what I have : [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/202jzptp/15/)

[image]

I'm not sure how to change the color of the inner area of the circle.

According to the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=en), I found that `chartArea.backgroundColor` is one of the **Configuration Options**, so I tried it in here

---

## JS

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', 11]
      ]);

      var options = {
          width: 160,
          height: 160,

          chartArea: {
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'

          },
          colors: ['#F46E4E', '#F9C262', '#ADB55E', ],
          legend: 'none',
          enableInteractivity: false,
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          pieHole: 0.85,
          //chartArea.backgroundColor:'pink' // Try it here

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Result, I still couldn't get to change the color.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm still not entirely sure how is it related to what I'm trying to achieve. Can you add a little more details ?

Comment: It isn't related. It's merely funny how someone over at Google thought it funny to put a pun in that sentence. Look up "shut your piehole".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, the piehole is not able to be colored using Google's config.

The `chartArea.backgroundColor` that you speak of correlates to the entire area that the chart area takes up, not the PieHole, you have a few options however.

This is where it will cover without any solution and correct syntax

**[Example with no solutions](https://jsfiddle.net/202jzptp/16/).**

Your second option is this, give the background a transparent background and use positioning to lay a div it behind your chart.

**[Example with div laid behind chart](https://jsfiddle.net/202jzptp/17/)**

As of right now, those seem to be the only option, i've read through the docs multiple times and there just isn't a way to specifically style the pieHole. Sorry it's not the solution you're looking for, but it will work, atleast.

`<div class="piehole"></div>`

```
.piehole{
    display:block;
    background:green;
    height:140px;
    width:140px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:100%;
    top:27px;
    left:23px;
}
```

JS Config

```
var options = {
                  width: 160,
                  height: 160,

                  chartArea: {
                      left: 10,
                      top: 20,
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '100%'

                  },
                  colors: ['#F46E4E', '#F9C262', '#ADB55E', ],
                  legend: 'none',
                  enableInteractivity: false,
                  pieSliceText: 'none',
                  pieHole: 0.85,
                  backgroundColor:'transparent'
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be achieved with ease with google charts. I would recommend a different approach, maybe a SVG using an `ellipse` and some `text-elements`.

Thinking something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/MANy1iSK0C80ZxNqD4o0?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use jQuery, you have another option is css3

Here is the example:

```css
circle {
  fill: yellowgreen;
  stroke: #655;
  stroke-width: 30;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle r="30" cx="50" cy="50" />
</svg>
```

Here is the full documentation
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/

[**Demo Link :**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4696e4c6700fe9f346d8)